Stripe 3DS2 - The payment attempt failed because additional action is required before it can be completed
I have a problem with Stripe 3DS2. In the most of payment everything works normal and customer can send his inquiry. And just for the record, at that moment we just reserve their money. Just in case when we accept their inquiry, we take their money. I use method paymentIntent as this app works in EU.
Sometimes, customer got an error:
"The payment attempt failed because additional action is required before it can be completed."
And the inquiry can not be sent. If I understood well, there is a problem with 3DS2 which in some cases request that customer accept transaction in their bank app.
At this moment I am not sure what to do because:
Stripe 3DS2 should automatically request bank authorization
I don’t see that is necessary to change or set some rules in Radar.
I'm testing with the card: 4000002760003184
https://docs.stripe.com/testing#authentication-and-setup
Stripe docs for 3ds: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/3d-secure/authentication-flow#controlling-when-to-present-the-3d-secure-flow
Fetch the client secret with JavaScript on the client side:
            const response = await axios.post(`/booking/${this.id}/payment-intent`);

            const { clientSecret } = response.data;

            const appearance = {
                theme: 'stripe',
            };
            this.elements = stripe.elements({ appearance, clientSecret });
            this.paymentElement = this.elements.create('payment', {
                fields: {
                    billingDetails: {
                        address: {
                            country: 'never',
                        },
                    },
                },
            });
            this.paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');

Create payment intent on the server side:
public function createPaymentIntent(int $id): array
    {

        $bookingRequest = $this->bookingRequestSessionHandler->retrieve($id);
        $amount = $bookingRequest->total()->getMinorAmount()->toInt();

        $options = [
            'capture_method' => 'manual',
        ];

        $payment = (new Reservation())->pay($amount, $options);

        return [
            'clientSecret' => $payment->client_secret
        ];
    }

Convert payment information collected by elements into a PaymentMethod and process it on the server.
           const { paymentMethod, error } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', this.paymentElement, {
                billing_details: {
                    address: {
                        country: this.customerCountry,
                    },
                },
            });
            if (error) {
                // Display "error.message" to the user...
                this.errorMessage = error.message;
                return;
            }
            // The card has been verified successfully...
            const data = {
                paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id,
            };
            axios
                .post(`/booking/${this.id}/process`, data)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.$emit('successBooking');
                })
                ....

private function processPayment($paymentMethodId, $reservation): void
    {

        $options = [
            'capture_method' => 'manual',
            'receipt_email' => $reservation->customer_email
        ];


        $payment = $reservation->charge(
            $reservation->total,
            $paymentMethodId,
            $options
        );

    }


Are these payments where the customer is present in the checkout flow? If you use Elements, Checkout, or Invoicing (one of the Stripe surfaces to collect payment), then 3ds should be presented to the customer automatically. If these payments are ones done with a previously saved card where the customer isn't present in your checkout flow, then you'll need to have some flow to bring them back online to complete 3ds authentication.

Yes, the customer is present in the checkout flow. I will edit the post and insert the code...

If I understand your code you're doing this:
1 - Create Payment Intent (server)
2 - Create payment element with client_secret (client)
3 - Create Payment Method with createPaymentMethod (client)
4 - Confirm Payment Intent with Payment Method ID (server)
The issue you're experiencing would be expected. createPaymentMethod does not authenticate the card. When you try to confirm from the server, the authentication hasn't been performed.
The simplest solution would be to replace 3 and 4 by a client-side confirmPayment function, and rely on webhooks / API polling to check on the status of your Payment Intent. This is the official integration:
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements
If you need to finalize the payment serverside, you have options to do this, but they're "alternative" as it's not as optimal when dealing with authentication:
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/finalize-payments-on-the-server
